# How to covert a list of lists into dataframe and make the first element of the lists as the index

Tags: python, pandas

The sample data of mine may be seen here:

```
data=[['Australia',100],['France',200],['Germany',300],['America',400]]
```

What I expect may be the dataframe like this:

```
           volume
Australia     100
France        200
Germany       300
America       400
```

And I've tried the following:

```
pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Country','Volume']) 
     Country  Volume
0  Australia     100
1     France     200
2    Germany     300
3    America     400

pd.DataFrame.from_items()
```

Howerver, I still can't get the expected result?

Is there a possible way that I can get the expected pandas dataframe structure?
Thanks for all your kindly checking in advance.

Comment: You can just do `pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Country','Volume']).set_index('Country') `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `set_index` on the result of the dataframe:

```
In [2]:
data=[['Australia',100],['France',200],['Germany',300],['America',400]]
pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Country','Volume']).set_index('Country') 

Out[2]:
           Volume
Country          
Australia     100
France        200
Germany       300
America       400
```

Comment: Wow, amazing!  It works.
Thanks a lot, it really help me.